# Rotating camera around a object positioned at center in openGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm reading OpenGL ES 2 for android.
In chapter 8 the question is to rotate the camera around the center of the table.

In other words...
The way I set the view matrix is as follows.

```
setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 0f, 1.2f, 2.2f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
```

Now I would like to rotate it around the origin around Y axis
What code should I write for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rotate around the center of the table, you have to translate the camera, and then set it's direction to point to the middle.

The position on the circle is pretty straightforward to calculate.

```
    float angle = 30.0f;
    float radius = 2.0f;

    float x = (float)( radius * Math.cos(angle));
    float y = (float)( radius * Math.sin(angle));

    Matrix.translateM(viewMatrix, 0, -x, 0, -y);
    Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 0f, 1.2f, 2.2f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
```